# Texto en posición vertical con FPDF en PHP

Tags: php

Muy buenas, intento simplemente poner un texto en vertical en una plantilla pdf con la librería fpdf en php.

He probado numerosas variantes pero no lo consigo. ¿Realmente es tan complicado poner un simple texto en vertical?

Tengo esto y se pinta en horizontal, pero lo quiero en vertical:

```
$pdf->Cell(0,150,'texto',0,0,'R');
```

Gracias

Comment: Mira un ejemplo en esta pagina, puede ser lo que buscas [http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script31.php](http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script31.php) Y este es el resultado [http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/ex31.pdf](http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/ex31.pdf) Igual te aconsejaría que uses MPDF que acepta HTML como parámetro y es mucho mas fácil trabajar con CSS [https://mpdf.github.io/](https://mpdf.github.io/)

Comment: Probé ese mismo ejemplo, pero no funciona. Da error 500 y rompe toda la plantilla

Comment: conoces MPDF? https://mpdf.github.io/

Comment: No puedo. Es un mantenimiento de mi trabajo y las plantillas ya se generan con FPDF. Necesitaría algo simple con ->cell pero veo que nada funciona

Comment: Si bien este enlace puede responder a la pregunta, es mejor incluir las partes esenciales de la respuesta aquí y proporcionar el enlace como referencia.  Las respuestas que son únicamente un enlace pueden dejar de ser válidas si la página vinculada cambia. - [Desde revisión](/review/low-quality-posts/295505)